# receive notifications using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsnotifications

Is it possible to receive notifications using `NSNotificationCenter` when my app is running in background if I set the plist key  "Required background modes" to the value "App plays voip" ?

So my question is : Is it possible to receive those notifications when my app is running in background since I set that apps as voip app ?

Comment: be aware that if your app is not a VOIP client, using the `App provides Voice over IP services` to get your app running in the background will result in your app being reject by Apple.

Comment: @rckoenes : thnaks for the reply and i undertsand the app rejections actually i am trying to create a voip app only and want to ensure how to check my app is still running in background.pls help

Answer (score 0):

For notifications, I use Parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

for Background notification using Urban Airship.

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push

**Tips--**

create account and application on urban.
https://go.urbanairship.com/

Send notification using this keyword ("content-available":1) in json string with your message.